# several hundred redirects, whats the most efficient way of configuring them?

Tags: redirect, apache-2.2, 301-redirect

I am aware that having too many redirects in a .htaccess file can lead to a loss of performance in apache, this leads me to my question is there a faster way to configure redirects in apache particularly if i have several hundred? i am also having to use a cpanel server in this instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you put them into `httpd.conf` instead of a `.htaccess` file? At least this way, apache only has to parse them once.

Alternatively, look at Apache's [RewriteMap directive in the mod_rewrite module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap). To quote:

> For plain text and DBM format files the looked-up keys are cached in-core until the `mtime` of the mapfile changes or the server does a restart. This way you can have map-functions in rules which are used for every request. This is no problem, because the external lookup only happens once!

In the grand scheme of things, 'several hundred' isn't a lot - I've known .htaccess files to have several thousand redirects - not necessarily wise, but not impossible.

Comment: thanks for the comments, am using cpanel so i know it effectively overwrites your httpd.conf everytime there is a change of that nature, i have heard of using include files so as to save the changes, just unsure of where they go and what format/filename

Comment: Have a look at the documentation [here](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/EasyApache3/InsideVHost)